# Как удалить учетную запись phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

случайно создал учетную запись в phpmyadmin не знаю как удалить. Помогите пожалуйста заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле phpMyAdmin создает учетные записи MySQL. Одна из которых может быть использована в качестве управляющей самого phpMyAdmin прописывается явно в config.inc.php (однако назначить ее можно только вручную, явно задав в конфигурационном файле).

Для удаления учетной записи MySQL-пользователя в phpMyAdmin выберите пункт "Учетные записи пользователей" выберите галку напротив пользователя, которого хотите удалить и нажмите кнопку "Вперед", после уточняющего запроса, учетная запись будет удалена.

Comment: Спасибо большое помогло.